# My recyclerview does not show my arraylist

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview, edit text and button. And when I write something and click button my recyclerview have to show what I have inserted. But when I insert and click on button nothing happens but when I click on the button with empty edit text it shows me empty text view.

**Here is my oncreate method:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        mRecyclerViewChat = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list_of_users);
        mInputMessageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
        mSendMessageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send_message);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerViewChat.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mChatList);
        mRecyclerViewChat.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    }
```

**Here is my onclick method:**

```
mSendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = mInputMessageText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (message != null && TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
                    mChatList.add(message);
                    mInputMessageText.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "message is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (chatAdapter != null){
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "chat adapter is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**And here is my adapter class:**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ChatViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<String> mChatList;
    public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<String> mChatList) {
        this.mChatList = mChatList;
    }
    @Override
    public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chat_box, parent, false);
        return new ChatViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChatViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.messageLeft.setText(mChatList.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChatList.size();
    }
    public class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageLeft, messageRight;
        public ChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            messageLeft = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_chat_box_left);
            messageRight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_chat_box_right);
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is my layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_bg">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messages_list_of_users"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/select_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"
                android:background="@color/white"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_message"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write a message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/send_message"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And if I enter nothing and click it shows me empty textview

Comment: Can u share your code for `recyclerview`, and make sure you have set `Layoutmanager` in your `recyclerview`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: have u check  log? fro any error and also share your `layout.xml`  with question  for me you current above code is looking fine

Comment: In your bind holder you just gave mchatlist.get(position) there nothing ahead of position ?

Comment: @Ashish Yes what I need to have there? I only want to display what I inserted

Comment: can you provide what is in mchatlist ? because you need to put position of your requirement

Comment: @NileshRathod I added layout file

Comment: @Ashish mchatlist is Arraylist<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter class, I don't see any method that's like the following:

```
public void addToChat(String message) {
    mChatList.add(message);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I'm assuming that the `mChatList` that's *added to* is inside your activity. Well, your recyclerview is not going to see that list since it's running off of a separate `mChatList` object of its own.

So in your clicker, with the method above implemented, you will need to modify as following:

```
if (chatAdapter != null) {
    chatAdapter.addToChat(message);
}
```

And you can still keep the other `mChatList.add(message);` if you wish, if you are still going to reference/update it.

But keep in mind that you have **two** `mChatList`; one in your activity and one in your adapter. While your recyclerview is initialized with the one from your activity, it is actually currently running off of the one from its adapter.

Note: oh, and yes, as Nilesh mentioned, you need to fix your condition as well.

```
if (message != null && TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
```

If message is *empty*? You must mean, if message is **not** empty:

```
if (message != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
```

Comment: I tried what you said and when I insert smth and send it shows me 2 empty textviews instead of 1. I guess it is because I use (chatAdapter.addToChat) and (mchatlist.add) and both of them gives me nothing empty\

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `if (message != null && TextUtils.isEmpty(message))` condition

You are checking **`message != null`** && **`TextUtils.isEmpty(message)`** which can not return true so change your condition

Try this

```
mSendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = mInputMessageText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (message != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
                    mChatList.add(message);
                    mInputMessageText.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "message is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (chatAdapter != null){
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "chat adapter is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is changed here?

Comment: @White i have Removed the  top  `layout` tag

Comment: I dont think that it will change smth but I will try

Comment: @White i found the problem please check updated answer

Comment: You added ! before Textutils?

Comment: I tried that and this changed. When I insert smth it shows me empty textview better than old one but not that I wanted

Comment: And I checked that my gettext is working and everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the array mChatList? because in your code I can't see where you are creating the list (mChatList = new ArrayList();) and your if condition in OnClickListener is wrong you have to put if(message != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) for your condition to work.

Comment: yes I am creating array and I tried !TextUtils.isEmpty but nothing better. When I changed that It only shows me empty textview